# Get details about function call

Tags: php, function, error-handling

In PHP, I'd like to get the details about a function call inside the function itself. The behavior I want (without doing this) is to have `debug_backtrace()` passed as an argument to the function.

I want that done automatically, for every call to a function.

I need this so I can have pre-defined errors for a fairly sizable project I'm working on, but I obviously want the line number of a central `trigger_error()` call, as that's not very useful for tracking down the problem. I also don't want to count on future developers to remember a `debug_backtrace()` argument.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Whats wrong with `debug_stacktrace()` and 2. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I said why I want to do it right in my question. Note the final paragraph beginning with "I need this...". Further, there is no such function as "debug_stacktrace()" (See here: http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=debug_stacktrace&lang=en ). I'd appreciate it if you'd actually read my question and remove what I assume is your downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that you can call `debug_backtrace()` yourself, and it would be pretty much the same. For instance:

```
function error(..params)
{
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
    array_shift($backtrace);
}
```

If you `array_shift` the given backtrace, if will be as if it were passed into the function.

If you aren't familiar with it:

> **array_shift()** shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving everything down.

Thus, because debug_backtrace() is numerically indexed, it will act the exact same.

Comment: It wouldn't be the same, as I need the details in the context of where the function was called, not where the function is defined.

Comment: `debug_backtrace()` doesn't really do anything in the ways of where a function was defined. Either you aren't clearly communicating something, or you don't understand how it works...

Comment: @Shadow Are you asking for a snapshot of the scope variables when a function is called and subsequently invokes a `trigger_error()`?

Comment: My appologies. I didn't realize that debug_backtrace contained the *full* backtrace. Probably the first time I've ever said this, but the PHP documentation doesn't communicate that very well.

Comment: @Shadow I tend to `print_r` almost every array I ever use that comes from PHP, just to make sure I know what is in it.